# Можно ли скопировать, изменить и сразу же вставить пару записей 1 запросом?

Tags: mongodb

Можно ли в mongodb скопировать пару записей, изменить некоторые поля и сразу же вставить переделанные записи? И все это 1 запросом.

Comment: Да можно используя [bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) метод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
db.SomeCollection.find(SomeCriteria).forEach(function(clone){
    //меняем произвольные поля
    clone.num=clone.num+1; //числовое
    clone.str=clone.str+"2"; //строковое

    delete clone._id; //затираем старый id
    db.SomeCollection.insert(clone);
});
```

`SomeCollection` и `SomeCriteria` - имя коллекции и требуемые критерии. `elem` - клонируемая запись